# swift get radians of rotating object while animating

Tags: swift, animation

hello i'm using this code for getting rotation by radians

```
let zKeyPath = "layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"
let imageRotation = (self.myUIImageView.valueForKeyPath(zKeyPath) as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0
```

but i'm not getting the current radians while the subview rotates. im getting only the start or the end of the animation

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I understand properties are set to their final values before an animation finishes, so you won't see the changes during the animation.

Comment: there must be a way to know the position/rotation of animating subview while animating